# gRPC: Converting circular structure to JSON

Tags: json, nestjs, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have this proto file code for login method:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package user;

service UserService {
  rpc Login (LoginRequest) returns (LoginResponse) {}
}

message LoginRequest {
  string email = 1;
  string password = 2;
}

message LoginResponse {
  string message = 1;
  User user = 2;
  string token = 3;
  string refreshToken = 4;
}

message User {
  string id = 1;
  string name = 2;
  string email = 3;
  string phone = 4;
}
```

The login method on user microservice:

```
async login(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const user = (await this.findByEmail(email)) as User;
            const comparepassword = await passwordService.comparePasswords(password, user.password);
            if (user && comparepassword) {
                const accessTokenPayload = {
                    id: user._id,
                    userType: user.type,
                };
                return { user, token, refreshToken };
            }

            return 'User not found';
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
        }
    }
```

The login controller on user microservice:

```
@GrpcMethod('UserService', 'Login')
    async login(@Payload() payload: Login): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const { email, password } = payload;
            const { user, token, refreshToken } = await this.usersService.login(email, password);

            return {
                message: 'Logged-In successfully.',
                user: {
                    email: user.email,
                    id: user.id,
                    name: user.name,
                    phone: user.phone,
                },
                token,
                refreshToken,
            };
        } catch (error) {
            console.trace(error);
            throw new RpcException(error);
        }
    }
```

The login method in API-gateway:

```
@Post('login')
    @HttpCode(200)
    async login(@Body() loginData: Login, @Res({ passthrough: true }) res: Response): Promise<any> {
        try {
            const user = await firstValueFrom(this.userService.Login(loginData));
            console.log(user)
            res.cookie('refreshToken', user.refreshToken, {
                httpOnly: true,
                sameSite: true,
            });
            delete user.refreshToken;

            return res.json({ message: 'Login successful.', data: user });
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Login failed');
        }
    }
```

I am getting this response in the API-gateway for user variable:

```
{
  message: 'Logged-In successfully.',
  user: {
    id: 'id',
    name: 'name',
    email: 'email',
    phone: '1234567890'
  },
  token: 'access-token',
  refreshToken: 'refresh-token'
}
```

Upon hitting the/login endpoint, Everything works fine, I am also getting the response in the postman but it also logs this error in the console:

```
ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property '_writableState' -> object with constructor 'WritableState'
    |     property 'afterWriteTickInfo' -> object with constructor 'Object'
    --- property 'stream' closes the circle
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your user object is has a socket, I assume it is an http.Response object. You should only add to the response json relevant data from the user object.